# AssaultCube Aimbot, my yaw and pitch values do not work

Tags: c++

My yaw and pitch values aren't working when I try use trigonometry, even though the math is wrong when I run my aimbot application it should at least aim at different angles when I move but that is not the case. It's just stuck in one angle looking there. My yaw value when I run the application gets infinitesimally close to 0 so I think my calculations are going beyond the yaw value interval

Note that the intervals for the yaw value are [ 0, 360 ] and pitch is [ -90, 90 ]

```
#include "proc.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <math.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#define PI 3.14159265
//WORD m_XPos = 0x04;
//WORD m_YPos = 0x08;
//WORD m_ZPos = 0xC
//WORD YawVal = 0x0040;
//WORD PitchVal = 0x0044;

int main()
{
    // Linking the game to my code essentially here
    DWORD procID;
    procID = getProcID(L"ac_client.exe");
    HANDLE handle = 0;
    handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);

    //base address for the player and base address for the enemy
    uintptr_t localBaseAddress = 0x50F4F4;
    uintptr_t entityBaseAddress = 0x50F4F8;

    // setting up a link to get the values of playerx,y,z and view angles
    std::vector<int> playerOffsets = { 0x4 };
    uintptr_t playerX = findDMAAddress(handle, localBaseAddress, playerOffsets);
    playerOffsets = { 0x8 };
    uintptr_t playerY = findDMAAddress(handle, localBaseAddress, playerOffsets);
    playerOffsets = { 0xC };
    uintptr_t playerZ = findDMAAddress(handle, localBaseAddress, playerOffsets);
    playerOffsets = { 0x40 };
    uintptr_t playerYaw = findDMAAddress(handle, localBaseAddress, playerOffsets);
    playerOffsets = { 0x44 };
    uintptr_t playerPitch = findDMAAddress(handle, localBaseAddress, playerOffsets);


    // setting up a link to get enemy x,y,z
    /* note this is just one enemy which is the second enemy in the entity list 
    chain */
    std::vector<int> enemyOffsets = { 0x8, 0x4 };
    uintptr_t enemyX = findDMAAddress(handle, entityBaseAddress, enemyOffsets);
    enemyOffsets = { 0x8, 0x8 };
    uintptr_t enemyY = findDMAAddress(handle, entityBaseAddress, enemyOffsets);
    enemyOffsets = { 0x8, 0xC };
    uintptr_t enemyZ = findDMAAddress(handle, entityBaseAddress, enemyOffsets);

    float myX = 0;
    float myY = 0;
    float myZ = 0;

    float botX = 0;
    float botY = 0;
    float botZ = 0;

    float placeholderX = 0;
    float placeholderY = 0;
    float placeholderZ = 0;

    float magnitude = 0;

    float tempYawValue = 0;
    float tempPitchValue = 0;
    float yawValue = 0;
    float pitchValue = 0;


    while (true)
    {
        // assign values to the floats i initialized previously for calculations
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)enemyX, &botX, sizeof(botX), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)enemyY, &botY, sizeof(botY), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)enemyZ, &botZ, sizeof(botZ), 0);

        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerX, &myX, sizeof(myX), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerY, &myY, sizeof(myY), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerZ, &myZ, sizeof(myZ), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerYaw, &tempYawValue, sizeof(tempYawValue), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerPitch, &tempPitchValue, sizeof(tempPitchValue), 0);

        //getting origin to get distance between me and enemy 
        placeholderX = botX - myX;
        placeholderY = botY - myY;
        placeholderZ = botZ - myZ;

        magnitude = sqrt(pow(placeholderX, 2) + pow(placeholderY, 2) + pow(placeholderZ, 2));

        //math for view angles
        yawValue = (atan2(tempYawValue, tempPitchValue)) * (180 / PI);
        pitchValue = acos(placeholderZ / magnitude) * (180 / PI);

        // constantly writing to player view angles memory usign the angles i calculated
        WriteProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerYaw, &yawValue, sizeof(yawValue), 0);
        WriteProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)playerPitch, &pitchValue, sizeof(pitchValue), 0);

    }

}
```

Comment: (isn't AssaultCube open-source? why do you need to find addresses?)

Comment: @user253751 I'm trying to learn an efficient way of getting addresses so I can learn for other games

Comment: If possible, please provide a [mre] of your problem.

Comment: Are you sure the calculations are correct? Do they work when you put them in the actual game code (since it's open-source)?

Comment: @user253751 magnitude for sure is correct. when i move closer to the enemy it gets close to 0, that would imply my view angles are correct too.

Comment: Note that atan2 has first argument y and second argument x, so maybe you swapped them? Also that multiplication by (180 / PI) looks suspicious -  should the result really be in degrees when input is in radians?

Comment: Magnitude is correct, yes. Are you sure the other ones are correct? I think that calculating an atan with a yaw makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: user253751 is correct, if yaw and pitch are angles, then using atan2 is senseless because atan2 needs two input coordinates